# Spring boot integration mybstis how to initialize the database through the wizard

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mybatis

I have an idea, to initialize the database connection through the following HTML page, instead of starting the project to initialize the database connection, I use springboot+mybatis, do not know how to achieve? Do you have any good suggestions or methods, thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVj4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

for example.mysql datasource.
in your controller;

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@GetMapping("/hello")
public Object getSM(){
    // change the settings here
    ((MysqlDataSource)dataSource).setUser("sdfs");
```

Comment: What I want is not this function. What I want is that springboot starts initialization without initializing mybatis, by calling some interface later, initializing mybatis into spring boot, and using some functions of mybatis.

Comment: for a singleton(by default ) spring will initialize it by itself. another way .you put beanDefinition into spring context by manual.